# Can I disable module menu items?

Tags: 7, routes

I have a module with a menu which I build like this:

in **moduleName.module**

```
function moduleName_menu() {
  $items = array(
    'title' => 'whatever',
    'page callback' => 'something_callback',
    ...
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM
  );
  return items;
}
```

Now I want certain items to be disabled (Clicking them should do nothing, similar to using `disabled="disabled"` on a `<input type="button">`). I tried adding `'#disabled' => true`, as I would do for form items, but that didn't work. How can I disable menu items?

**UPDATE**

I tried using `myTheme_menu_link` to disable the menu items. So in the code above, I add `'disabled' => true` or `'disabled' => false` to certain menu items. Then, my `theme_menu_link` function looks like this:

```
function vitrine_menu_link(array $variables) {
    $element = $variables['element'];
  $sub_menu = '';

  if ($element['#below']) {
    $sub_menu = drupal_render($element['#below']);
  }
  $output = l($element['#title'], $element['#href'], $element['#localized_options']);
  if (isset($element['disabled']) && $element['disabled']) {
    error_log('Hoping to see this somewhere in the log');
    $output = '<a>' . $element['#title'] .  '</a>';
  }
  return '<li' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . $output . $sub_menu . "</li>\n";    
}
```

I test it by emptying all caches, which rebuilds the menu, but still, the error I'm trying to log never get's logged. It seems as though my `'disabled' => true` never makes it to this function...

Comment: Can you specify what you mean with "unclickable"? What is your actual goal?

Comment: @enzipher See my edit. Is that clearer?

Answer (score 1):

This can only be done on the theme layer. Try taking a look at [`theme_menu_link()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/theme_menu_link/7).

Comment: That means modifying `drupal/includes/menu.inc`. Isn't there a way to do this from within `drupal/sites/all/themes/myTheme`?

Comment: @Shawn No need to modify menu.inc, you can override theme functions in your theme's template.php file with a naming convention: `function MYTHEME_menu_link($vars)`. Once you clear the caches your version of the function will be called for any invocation of `theme('menu_link');`

Comment: This is not working. It looks like the `key=>value` pair I'm adding to my menu items is no longer there when I get to `myTheme_menu_link`. I will edit my question to show some code.

Comment: How are you adding your key=>value to the item before it goes to the theme function? This would need to be done in a preprocess function. Or you could just do the logic in the theme function itself.

Comment: I'm adding the key=>value pair in moduleName.module when creating the menu. It seems this is a mistake anyways since that code is only executed once when installing the module, not everytime a page with that menu is loaded (which is what I would need)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can't disable links in that way. Depending on what you want to do I believe your options are either to add a class, programmatically or by using the [Menu attributes module](http://drupal.org/project/menu_attributes), and then use jQuery to disable the link, or not linking the menu item at all.

**First option**
Add a class or an id to the link, and do something like this to disable the link:

```
$('#linkid').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

**Second option**
Use the [Special menu items module](http://drupal.org/project/special_menu_items) with the `<nolink>` option, which results in a menu item that is not linked, i.e. no `<a>` tag. You could of course do this programmatically as well, but the module is rather simple and straight forward.

This is more general solutions for menu items, which I realize it's not exactly what you are asking (a solution to your code), but it does provides solutions for your question *"Can I disable module menu items?"*.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the nifty `menu_attributes` contributed project. (You can download it from [here](http://drupal.org/project/menu_attributes)) or just `hook_menu_link_alter()` ([documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_link_alter/7)) around which that module is built.

Both these approaches allow you to add attributes (including classes) to menu links.